# How to determine the variable in a integral function for linear fitting

Tags: integration, linear-regression, python, programming

I want to apply my data to the equation
$$
\frac{D_t-D_0}{D_m-D_t}
 = V_0 \int \exp\left(-\frac{E_a}{RT_\mathrm{mean}(t)}\right)\ \mathrm{d}t
$$
and determine the $E_a$ for linear regression between left and the integral. So the result can look like this:

[image: linear fit]

The left of the equation is $f(t)$ and I can calculate that. I know $V_0$ and $R$ on the right. I have data for $T(t)$ but no formula. I need to do it in Python.

Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the bounds on the integral? What are the known/ unknown quantities?